# How to upload documents in IBM Watson from salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, watson

I have incorporated IBM Watson APIs in my Salesforce org. I am able to see AddDocumentOptionsBuilder apex class but was looking for an example which leverages it. My intent is to add an apex trigger which will fire whenever a file is uploaded in Salesforce, and uploads the same in IBM watson collection.